# Using Redux connect() with Layout component being passed children and receiving props

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-persist

I'm having some difficulty getting my Layout component to connect because I'm passing children. Basically the way I have my application setup is that app.js houses the provider, persistgate, layout, and react-navigation navigation stack.

The only component which I haven't connected so far is my Layout, and before I started to implement some navigation on the top bar, I didn't really need it. Now I want to be able to pass the routeName to redux so that the Layout knows which route the user is on and can display appropriate buttons.

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work, if I manage to get the Layout to load with connecting, it doesn't seem to obtain the routes from redux store even though I've confirmed that it is there on React-Native Debugger.

`app.js`

```
export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                    <Layout>
                        <AppWithNavigationState/>
                    </Layout>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

`Layout.js`
This is what I used BEFORE.

```
    class Layout extends Component {

  render() {
      const currentRoute = this.props.route;
      console.log(this.props.route); ////// TESTING TO SEE IF ROUTES SHOWS. IT'S ALWAYS "UNDEFINED" DESPITE BEING IN THE STORE.
     headerButton = () => {
          if (currentRoute==='Main') { 
                return (<Icon onPress={() => navigate({routeName: "PostForm"})} style={styles.headericon} name="back"></Icon>);
            } else {
                return (<Icon style={styles.headericon} name="menu"></Icon>)
            }
        }

.......
export default ({children}) => (
    <Layout>
        {children}
    </Layout>
)
```

`Layout.js  Test (updated but still not receiving store data)`

```
Layout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    route: PropTypes.string,
    updateRoute: PropTypes.func
 };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    route: state.route.route
 });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateRoute: route => dispatch(postActions.updateRoute(route))
    }
}

const LayoutTest = ({children}) => (
    <Layout>
        {children}
    </Layout>
)


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LayoutTest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I do not even need to pass 'children' to the components. I rendered it by changing

```
export default ({children}) => (
    <Layout>
        {children}
    </Layout>
)
```

to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout)
```

After doing some testing and realizing that the state was actually able to be read inside of the mapStateToProps function but it was not mapping to Layout. The reason I was so confused was that I really thought I needed to pass children to it the way I had it before. Luckily I never!